# Homework. Merge Sort, fill in the blanks

Tags: java, loops, sorting, conditional-statements, mergesort

This is a fill in the blanks problem. I cannot delete and rewrite things. What I filled in are the lines after "//TO DO .... and before, "is/was my answer, the line above, correct?

My question is are 1, 2, 3a-d, and 4 correct and if so why am I getting a stack overflow error.

As of now this returns a stack overflow error. My background is one half an introductory course in java and now Im in over my head in data structures and algorithms.

**Assignment:**
Merge Sort

Develop merge sort method, which will sort an array of integer values

There are four places that you need to make modifications to 
properly execute the sort. Each of these places is labeled with documentation →
// TO DO (#1), (#2), (#3a-d)and (#4).

If you run the application and input ‘8’, 
the output should be identical to that listed.

Sample Output:

The sample output below shows the MergeSort algorithm, with logs of debug output 
to show the progression of the algorithm:

Merge Sort Test

Enter Number of Integer Elements:

8

Enter 8 integer elements

Element 1: 6

Element 2: 5

Element 3: 3

Element 4: 1

Element 5: 7

Element 6: 8

Element 7: 2

Element 8: 4

Calling sort: low [0], high [4]

Calling sort: low [0], high [2]

Calling sort: low [0], high [1]

Calling sort: low [1], high [2]

Merging 2 Elements

Current Array: 5 6

Calling sort: low [2], high [4]

Calling sort: low [2], high [3]

Calling sort: low [3], high [4]

Merging 2 Elements

Current Array: 1 3

Merging 4 Elements

Current Array: 1 3 5 6

Calling sort: low [4], high [8]

Calling sort: low [4], high [6]

Calling sort: low [4], high [5]

Calling sort: low [5], high [6]

Merging 2 Elements

Current Array: 7 8

Calling sort: low [6], high [8]

Calling sort: low [6], high [7]

Calling sort: low [7], high [8]

Merging 2 Elements

Current Array: 2 4

Merging 4 Elements

Current Array: 2 4 7 8

Merging 8 Elements

Current Array: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Elements After Sorting

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

```
package mergesort;

import java.util.Scanner;

/* Class MergeSort */
public class MergeSort 
{
   /* Merge Sort function */
   public static void sort( int[] array, int low, int high ) 
   {
      int      diff;
      int      midpoint;

      /* Calculate Difference between low and high */
      diff = high-low;         

      /* Recursion is called until diff is less than or equal to 1 */
      /* Return if less than or equal to 1 */
      if ( diff <= 1 ) 
      {
         return; 
      }

      /* Calculate the midpoint between low and diff */
      midpoint = low + diff/2; 

      // We will call sort recursively here, once for the lower half of the 
      // provided array and once for the upper half of the array
      System.out.printf( "Calling sort: low [%d], high [%d]\n", low, midpoint );
```

**// TO DO (#1): Sort Lower Half of Array**

```
 sort(array, low, midpoint);
```

**Is my answer, the line above, correct?**

```
      System.out.printf( "Calling sort: low [%d], high [%d]\n", midpoint, high );
```

**// TO DO (#2): Sort Higher Half of Array**

```
 sort(array, high - midpoint, high);
```

**Is my answer, the line above, correct?**

```
      // Merge Two Sorted Subarrays
      // Create temporary array and temporary variables
      int[] temp = new int[diff];
      int i = low, j = midpoint;

      System.out.printf( "Merging %d Elements\n", diff );
      for ( int k = 0; k < diff; k++ ) 
      {
         // Fill in temporary array as necessary
         if ( i == midpoint )
         {
```

**TO DO (#3a) I am completely lost when it comes to how these two things are merged and why is requires a 4 conditions. I would have preferred to code this from scratch.**

```
     temp[k] = array[j++];
```

**Was my answer, the line above, correct?**
             }
             else if ( j == high )

```
         {
```

**// TO DO (#3b)**

```
 temp[k] = array[i++];
```

**Was my answer, the line above, correct?**

```
         }
         else if ( array[j] < array[i] ) 
         {
```

**// TO DO (#3c)**

```
 temp[k] = array[j++];
```

**Was my answer, the line above, correct?**

```
 }
         else 
         {
```

**// TO DO (#3d)**

```
temp[k] = array[i++];
```

**Was my answer, the line above, correct?**

```
     }
  }    

      System.out.print( "Current Array: " );
      for ( int k=0; k<diff; k++ ) 
      {
```

**// TO DO (#4): Fill in array with temporary array elements**

```
  array[k] = temp[k];
```

**Was my answer, the line above, correct?**

```
System.out.printf( "%d ", array[low+k] );
          }

      System.out.println();
   }


   /* Main method */
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );        
      int     elements, lp;
      int     intArray[] = null;

      System.out.println( "Merge Sort Test\n" );

      /* Accept number of elements */
      System.out.println( "Enter Number of Integer Elements: " );
      elements = keyboard.nextInt();

      /* Create array of n elements */
      intArray = new int[ elements ];

      /* Read Elements from the keyboard */
      System.out.println( "\nEnter " + elements + " integer elements" );
      for ( lp=0; lp<elements; lp++ )
      {
         System.out.print( "Element " + ( lp+1 ) + ": " );
         intArray[lp] = keyboard.nextInt();
      }
      /* Call method sort */
      sort( intArray, 0, elements );

      /* Print sorted Array */
      System.out.println( "\nElements After Sorting" );        

      for ( lp=0; lp<elements; lp++ )
      {
         System.out.print( intArray[lp] + " " );            
      }
      System.out.println();            
   }    
}
```

Comment: that's a lot of explanation. Can you mark in bold exactly what it is you're having trouble with?

Comment: if you'd rather code merge sort from scratch like you say in one comment, why not do so? When you have that, it should be easier to fill out the missing bits in this answer based on that

Comment: Sounds like a good time to learn to use a debugger. Use this as a reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort

Comment: The first line of #2 should be `sort(array, midpoint, high);` . First line of #3a should be `temp[k] = array[j++];` . See if you can fix the rest.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you! :) I didn't just fix it, but understand why it was wrong.  What I dont understand is why the error was specifically a stackoverflow error, but that's an answer that's too advanced for me right now.

Comment: The stack overflow problem was due to the first line of #2. `high - midpoint` is less than midpoint. Take the case low = 4, midpoint = 6, high = 8, then high-midpoint = 2, so what should be a split into 2 elements is instead a split into 6 elements. Then it's low = 2, midpoint = 5, high = 8, and high-midpoint is 3, so then it's low = 3, midpoint = 5, high = 8, and high-midpoint = 3, which where it just  repeats until stack overflow.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you professor. Very clear.  I wasn't thinking about all conditions.  1. I thought, worse assumed high was the last index,  when it was the size of the array so I thought starting from the midpoint would cause as overlap.  2. I didn't think about all cases.  I thought about low =0 and 8 = high. I didn't think about the next recursion. Again,  thank you for the clear and helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort(array, low, midpoint);
2. sort(array, midpoint, high);

You can't make any assumptions. If you look at the main method, "high" is not included. High is the length of the array, not the index of the last element.

3a.

```
temp[k] = array[j++];
```

This means:

```
temp[k] = array[j];
j++;
```

Why? This is in case you reach the end of one half of the array before you reach the end of the other. It's saying if you have completed copying the first sorted half to the temp array then take from the next half and increment the index for that array.

3b.

```
temp[k] = array[i++];
```

Why? See above.

3c.

```
temp[k] = array[j++];
```

Meaning, put the smaller int in the temp array and increment the index for the half it came from.
3d.
The only remaining condition is the opposite of that above. In that case you do the opposite:

```
temp[k] = array[i++];
```

4. Copy the temp array to the original array:

   array[k] = temp[k];